# Autofac Generic Repository Service Multiple DBSet

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, repository, autofac

I'm new to Autofac and repository. I downloaded an MVC sample project and I'm working on it. I have a database and several interrelated tables. There is a `Customer` repo service in the MVC `Controller`.

I have several property classes in the customer class.

I want to add a new record. But I also need to add records to the nested classes. One Customer service is added to the parameter of the constructive method.

How can I access other tables in controller.

What is the best way for that.

```
 private readonly IService<SubCustomer> _serviceSubCust;
    private readonly IService<Customer> _serviceCust;
    private readonly IService<Document> _serviceDoc;
    private readonly int _pageSize;

    public DocumentTransactionController(
        IService<SubCustomer> serviceSubCust,
        IService<Customer> serviceCust,
        IService<Document> serviceDoc)
    {
        _serviceCust = serviceCust;
        _serviceSubCust = serviceSubCust;
        _serviceDoc = serviceDoc;
        _pageSize = 10;
    }
```

Comment: Just letting you know, asp.net core has built in dependency injection, It might be more friendly, especially if you are starting from scratch with MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the services are registered inside your startup.cs, start with data access and simple data writing. You didn't post your service methods so I'm going to take a black box stab at what is in there.

Perhaps you have a method inside your `_serviceCust` that exposes your Customer list, or it has various methods such as `GetCustomerList()`, or `CreateCustomer(Customer cust)`. The magic of services is that you can store reusable logic and access it from your controller. In this case, the best use of a service is a method that can update nested structures for you in the database.

If you want to create a Customer, start in your controller

```
var bobCustomer= new Customer()
    {
         Name = "Bob",
         Profession = "Builder",
         Document = docObject, //you need a prepared document object here   
    };
```

Then you would call your service using `_serviceCust.CreateCustomer(bobCustomer)`

If you want to learn more advanced methods of updating database tables, look into [transaction contexts](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/working-with-transaction-in-entity-framework-6-0/). They will allow you to piece-by-piece manipulate your database and still maintain ACIDity.

If you had to have logic in your controller, however, you could do the following pseudocode

```
using(var ctx = new ContextTransaction()){
    var customer = new Customer();//...create customer object...
    _serviceCust.Update(customer);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
    var sub = new SubCustomer();
    sub.ParentCustomer = customer.Id; //use the customer id as a foreign key for your subcustomer
    _serviceSubCust.Update(sub);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
    //use the subcustomer id as a foreign key for your other nested classes, so on so forth...
    ctx.Commit();
}
```

Comment: Document = docObject, <<<--- 

In this section, I want to look at the document repository and call if there are any documents. Or create a new one.
Should i add repo to the controller every time.?

Comment: @user13306484 in that case you should use _serviceDoc to grab your data. probably something called _serviceDoc.GetDocument(id)